# Jquery append css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple image zoom script.

http://jsfiddle.net/GbDw9/1051/

The problem is that margin style applies only after second a[data-onclick="zoom"] click.

Why so?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and all i can see is a hide/show image behavior, what zoom are you mentioning? do I need to try with different browsers? any chance to show in a image what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[data-onclick="zoom"]').click(function () {
   $('body')
       // append complete
       .append('<div id="image-zoom"><span id="close"></span><img src="http://samurai.releasetracker.ru/media/images/movie/original/jCH93cL8b6uYVK9jWs6xw3IvQbA_1.jpg"></div>')
       // find last appended div
       .find('#image-zoom:last')
       // giving CSS
       .css({
         'margin': '-' + ($('#image-zoom > img').height() / 2) + 'px 0 0 -' + ($('#image-zoom > img').width() / 2) + 'px'
       });
   return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GbDw9/1059/)**

#### Note

you're using `image-zoom` as `id`, but if you want to multiple item the same `id` then change `id` to `class`, because same `id` for multiple element is a document page is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something different, like:

```
  $("a[data-onclick='zoom']").click(function() {

    // remove if exists
    if($(".image-zoom").length > 0)
      $(".image-zoom").remove();

    // add image
    $("<img />", { 
      "src": $(this).attr("data-image"), 
      "class": "image-zoom" }).appendTo("body");

    // get image size
    var h = $(".image-zoom").height(),
        w = $(".image-zoom").width();

    //animate
    $(".image-zoom")
      .css({
        "height": 0
      })
      .animate(
      {
        "opacity": 1,
        "height": h
      }, 1000);

      return false;
  });
```

where in the HTML you would have:

```
<a href="#" 
   data-onclick="zoom" 
   data-image="http://samurai.releasetracker.ru/media/images/movie/original/jCH93cL8b6uYVK9jWs6xw3IvQbA_1.jpg"
   >click</a>
```

Here is a **[live demo](http://jsbin.com/asefey/2/edit#preview)**.

If, as I said in my comment, is this what you're trying to accomplish...